# can't find or edit java class in eclipse under svn

Tags: java, eclipse, search

I am working on a large open source project that is under svn and Maven.  As I try to get my head around the various classes and methods contained in the project I realised that I can't search for class names with the usual eclipse search feature (e.g. Ctrl + Shift + T).  I can't even modify a class without getting this error:

**"This compilation unit is not on the build path of a java project"**

.. I kind of guess what that means but I don't really understand why it says that.  I mean I just checked out the project from svn and imported it in eclipse like I do usually.

I have also pasted a screenshot to give an idea of where I am in the project when I am attempting these simple tasks.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in this project and give me some direction on how to sort this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems <s>likely</s> possible that the Subversion files did not include a Java build path for Eclipse and that you have not created one. That will be stored in the .classpath file after you go to Project > Properties and specify the locations of your source folders (possibly among other things, such as libraries).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to add src/main to .classpath but my Eclipse has crashed as a result.. Now I can't reopen it..  Will restart my laptop and check again tomorrow

Comment: I have added <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" /> to the .classpath file shown in the screenshot but it doesn't help.

Comment: OK, your project has what Eclipse calls "Maven nature" (that is, it's managed by m2e) as shown by the little M. In this case you shouldn't have to edit the .classpath. But your project is missing the little J for "Java nature". I'm not sure precisely what to do in this case. I'm sure an expert such as Lars @vogella would know. (Sorry, I'm being a little lazy--I could of course try for myself to install Eclipse and import this open-source project.)

Comment: thanks I managed to add the Java nature and can now edit the  java files, however the java files are still not on the build path.  I tried adding AlgoTrader/code in build path but I get tons of red crosses in my java files.  That said I guess your comment has helped put me on the right path so I am going to accept it. Thanks again